# To generate random numbers in java from given set of numbers

Tags: java, random, numbers

Is it possible to generate random no. from the given set of no. like 5, 50, 20?
If so please give simple example
thanks.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Build an array. `int[] vals = {5, 50, 20};` - pick a random value from that array. Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class RandomNumbers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };

    Random r = new Random();
    int nextRandomNumberIndex = r.nextInt(randomNumbers.length);
    System.out.println(randomNumbers[nextRandomNumberIndex]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Random.nextInt()` to get a random `index`.

Use that `index` to get you pseudo random element:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
int randomIndex = Random.nextInt(arr.length);
int randomVal = arr[randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class randomFromList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int[] arr = {5, 50, 20}; // any set of numbers of any length
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // prints out 100 random numbers from the list
            x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, arr.length); // random number
            System.out.println(arr[x]); // item at random index
        }    
    }
}
```

It is better to use [java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) as of Java 1.7+. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java) for why. However, if you're using a version that predates Java 1.7, use [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)